# Graph level connectivity processing takes huge space and time

Tags: java, graph-theory

I am writing a code for finding the K-level connectivity of the graph

```
G = (V,E).
```

The graph is called 2-level connectivity if there are at least two disjoint paths between any two random chosen vertices in the graph `G`.

When the graph is small (has low number of vertices) the DFS or any search takes a small amount of time, but when handling large graphs such as 100 vertices, the search techniques will take a huge amount of time and memory.

Here is the code which I used to find the level of connectivity using Java:

```
public static List<List<Integer>> list_of_all_path; // record all the paths of the graph

public static int connectivity_level_CR(Graph g) {
    list_of_all_path = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    int minimum_level = 10000000; // high number

    for (int z = 0; z < vNumber; z++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < vNumber; l++) {
            if (z != l) {
                g.printPaths(z, l);
                if (listOfLists.size() < minimum_level) {
                    minimum_level = listOfLists.size(); // record the minimum number of paths between two nodes
                }
            }        
        }
    }
    if (!(is_the_network_connected(g))) minimum_level = 0; // if the network is disconnected, the connectivity level is zero
    return minimum_level;
}

public void printPaths(int s, int d) {
    listOfLists.clear();
    Boolean[] visited = new Boolean[vNumber];
    Integer[] path = new Integer[vNumber];
    int path_index = 0;
    count_paths = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vNumber; i++) {
        visited[i] = false;
    }

    printPathsUtil(s, d, visited, path, path_index);
}

//find the paths in the graph
int count_paths = 0;

public void printPathsUtil(int s, int d, Boolean[] visited, Integer[] path, int path_index) {
    visited[s] = true;
    path[path_index] = s;
    path_index++;

    if (s == d) {
        //List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(path);
        //listOfLists.add(intList);
        List<Integer> path_of = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < path_index; i++) {
            //System.out.print(path[i] + " ");
            path_of.add(path[i]);
        }
        listOfLists.add(path_of);
        //list_of_all_path.add(path_of);      
        //System.out.println();
    } else {  
        ArrayList<Integer> list = adj[s];
        for (Integer i : list) {
            if (!visited[i])
                printPathsUtil(i, d, visited, path, path_index);
        }
    }

    path_index--;
    visited[s] = false;
}
```

The code is known and exists on the internet. The code just chooses one of the nodes, `V`, in turns and starts searching and counting all of the paths. Thus the code will return the minimum number of disjoint paths between any two random nodes which is at the K-connectivity level.

My question is:

As illustrated above, the the search method is not good for large graphs,
so is there any method, code, or mathematical theory that can return the K-connectivity level of large graph with a small amount of time and memory?

Suppose that the large graph contains 100 vertices and is strongly connected, which means it has at least 2-level connectivity.

Comment: By "disjoint paths" do you mean "have no common vertices" or "have no common edges"?

Comment: I think your code email considers the same edge for several paths between two vertices. For example, I think `printPathsUtil(0,2,Booleans[4],Integer[4],0)` adds 2 paths to `listOfLists` (which I assume should be `list_of_all_paths`) given `adj=[{1}, {0,2,3},{1,3},{2,1}]`. - it happens because the recursion ignores the past and looks at the smaller problem as a new one. Between vertex 1 and 3 there are 2 paths. But only one edge leads from 0 to 1.

Comment: the disjoint paths means like this :
A->B->c->e
A->B->K->e   so the paths from A to e not similar, so yes I have to go to smaller paths in between , this is my problem and takes large time and space

Comment: The paths you gave now are not disjoint in either definition because they have the edge A->B in common. So counting them as 2 disjoint paths is wrong anyway. My question is whether A->B->C and A->D->B->E->C are considered disjoint or not for the purpose of your question. (both vertex-independent and egde-independent definitions exist. Which one does the connectivity definition use?)

Comment: yes ,considered disjoint

also even if A->B is common but considered as two different paths

Comment: You're not using the term "disjoint" correctly. It means "not having in common". According to [the wiki page for k-edge-connected graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-edge-connected_graph) (look at the alternative cahracterisation under the Formal Definition section), for the definition of edge-connectivity (which I believe is what you refer to as level-connectivity) you need the edge-disjoint, meaning no two paths can share an edge. So your example is **not** 2 edge-disjoint paths. My example is, as there is no edge used in both paths there.